# Registration with Devise with only email field on page with other form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I want to give users posibility to add content not being registered but show 'registration form' above submit button on my 'content form'. How to do that using Devise gem? Or maybe I should use some other gems for this functionality?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can register the user in the back-end (for default configuration):

```
user = User.new(params[:user])
if user.save!
  #some logic, where user adds content
else
  #some logic
```

If you want to register only with the email, you will need to generate a password, and for example, send it to the user email. See more there: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Automatically-generate-password-for-users-(simpler-registration)/

Answer (score 1):

Generated in standard view user login is default by email. If you wont show registeration form directly in place you want put render file with registeration form:

```
<%= render :file => 'users/registrations/new' %>
```

I propose to review the wiki: [How To: Add sign_in, sign_out, and sign_up links to your layout template](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Add-sign_in,-sign_out,-and-sign_up-links-to-your-layout-template)
and RailsCasts: [Episode 210](http://railscasts.com/episodes/210-customizing-devise)